# A group generated by three rational points has actually two generators?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Consider three points on the plane: $(1,0), (0,1) $and $(\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n})$, where $p,q,m,n\in\mathbb Z, q,n\neq 0,\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(m,n)=1.$

The group generated by $(1,0), (0,1) $and $(\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n})$ with respect to addition can be denoted as
$$\Gamma=\{k_1(1,0)+k_2(0,1)+k_3(\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n})\mid k_1,k_2,k_3\in \mathbb Z\}\\=
\{(k_1+k_3\frac{p}{q},k_2+k_3\frac{m}{n})\mid k_1,k_2,k_3\in \mathbb Z\}.$$

After trying some examples, I feel that $\Gamma$ can actually be generated by its two elements(e.g., when $(\frac{p}{q},\frac{m}{n})=(\frac{2}{5},\frac{4}{5})$, $\Gamma=<(\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5}),(\frac{2}{5},-\frac{1}{5})>$), but the general proof may require some knowledge of number theory(?) which is my weakness.

I was wondering if my guess is correct and if anybody would be willing to share his or her ideas about this question. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's just make things simpler by making everything integer: So instead of $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(p/q,m/n)$, we can use $(qn,0)$, $(0,qn)$, and $(pn,mq)$ by multiplying all the vectors by a constant factor of $qn$. This group is isomorphic to our original group, since we're just scaling everything with a constant factor, so if we show this group can be generated with two elements, then the original group must also be able to be generated with two elements.

Now, we can make a matrix over the integers where each of the rows of our matrix represents a lattice basis:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
qn & 0 \\
0 & qn \\
pn & qm
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
The nice thing about matrices with integer entries is that they have a [Hermite normal form](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hermite+normal+form#GilbertPathria90), which means we can always multiply them on the left by some integer square matrix which is invertible over the integers (i.e. the matrix is invertible and its inverse is also an integer square matrix) in order to put the matrix in upper triangular form. In other words, there exists integers $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l$ such that:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
qn & 0 \\
0 & qn \\
pn & qm
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
j & l \\
0 & k \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
This relates to the original group, because we can express this matrix multiplication as three equations in our group:
$$(j,l)=a(qn,0)+b(0,qn)+c(pn,qm)$$
$$(0,k)=d(qn,0)+e(0,qn)+f(pn,qm)$$
$$(0,0)=g(qn,0)+h(0,qn)+i(pn,qm)$$
Thus, $(j,l)$ and $(0,k)$ are elements of our group (the last equation can be ignored since $(0,0)$ is not useful). However, the matrix on the left-hand side is invertible, which means we can multiply both sides on the left by the inverse:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
qn & 0 \\
0 & qn \\
pn & qm
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
a' & b' & c' \\
d' & e' & f' \\
g' & h' & i'
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
j & l \\
0 & k \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
And now we get three equations looking like this:
$$(qn,0)=a'(j,l)+b'(0,k)+c'(0,0)$$
$$(0,qn)=d'(j,l)+e'(0,k)+f'(0,0)$$
$$(pn,mq)=g'(j,l)+h'(0,k)+i'(0,0)$$
We can ignore the $(0,0)$ term, so this shows that we can express $(qn,0), (0,qn), (pn,mq)$ all in terms of just $(j,l)$ and $(0,k)$, so $\{(j,l),(0,k)\}$ is a generating set for our group, showing that our group can indeed be generated by two elements!

This kind of group, where we are taking linear combinations of different points in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is called a [lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(group)) and every lattice in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is generated by a set of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you have a generating set for a lattice which is not linearly independent, then you can find a linearly independent generating set using the Hermite normal form. There are also other algorithms to find a linearly independent generating set for a lattice, and [there's already a MathOverflow question about this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331446/find-a-lattice-basis-given-too-many-points).

If you want to do this yourself without learning all these algorithms, I would recommend using a computer algebra system where this is built-in, like [LatticeReduce in Wolfram Alpha](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LatticeReduce.html). For instance, for the example you gave of a lattice generated by $(1,0),(0,1),(2/5,4/5)$, [WolframAlpha easily finds a linearly independent generating set for this lattice](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=LatticeReduce%5B%7B%281%2C0%29%2C%280%2C1%29%2C%282%2F5%2C4%2F5%29%7D%5D): $\{(1/5,2/5), (-2/5,1/5)\}$.

Comment: This works (+1). But whenever I teach this topic (structure theory of finitely generated modules over a Euclidean domain or a PID) I begin with the resul stating that a submodule of a finitely generated free module of rank $n$ over a PID (here $\Bbb{Z}$) is itself free and of rank $\le n$. I rather think that the same approach to that piece of a theory is used rather universally (not just me). And settles the claim immediately together with your idea (a good one at that!!) to scale things to happen inside $\Bbb{Z}^2$. It all comes much to the same thing anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible if you have some extra condition. We hope that $\Gamma=\{(\frac{k_1}{q},\frac{k_2}{n})\mid k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ so that $(\frac{1}{q},0)$ and $(0,\frac{1}{n})$ are enough.

Thus, gcd$(q,n)=1$ will meet our need.

Using Bézout's identity, we have $k_1,k_3$ such that $$k_1q+k_3p=1$$ Moreover, by adding $k_3$ with integer divided by $q$, we still can find corresponding $k_1$ to keep this dentity. As gcd$(q,n)=1$ implies gcd$(mq,n)=1$, we can choice proper $k_3$ such that $n\mid k_3m$. Now, by choice proper $k_2$, we finally get point $(\frac{1}{q},0) \in \Gamma$.

Note that gcd$(q,n)=1$ also implies gcd$(q,pn)=1$. You can proof $(0,\frac{1}{n})\in \Gamma$ similarly.

I believe that you can generalize the conclusion by studying gcd$(q,n)$.